# biblatex: no pages for article

Tags: biblatex

I have to cite articles without page numbers, book sections however are supposed to have them.
I'm using the following code to avoid the "pp." before the pages:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{pages={}}
```

Obviously, this omits page numbers for all citations. Is there a way to have only the articles without page numbers?

Comment: Just to be clear: Should this apply for the bibliography, or for in-text-citations, or for both?

Comment: Which bibliography style are you using? I think the easiest option might be to duplicate it in your `texmf` folder and change it. For instance, in many styles you could remove (or comment) the line that says `\printfield{pages}` under `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}`.

Comment: It is for the authoryear-style and only in the bibliography.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to change the format of the `pages` field  which deals with page ranges of articles, incollections etc. in the bibliography. (There's also a `pagetotal` field for the total pages of, e.g., books.) The optional argument of `\DeclareFieldFormat` takes a comma-separated list of entry types for which the new/changed format should apply.

Changing the format for in-text-citations requires to fiddle with the `postnote` field; see section 3.11.3 of the `biblatex` manual for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}%

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},
}
@incollection{Fis00,
  author = {Fischel, William A.},
  year = {2000},
  title = {Zoning and land use regulation},
  maintitle = {Encyclopedia of law and economics},
  volume = {2},
  booktitle = {Civil law and economics},
  editor = {Boudewijn, Bouckaert and de Geest, Gerrit},
  location = {Cheltenham},
  publisher = {Elgar},
  pages = {403--442},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocites[887]{Bli74}[403]{Fis00}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: iennisei's answer makes me think I may have misunderstood your question: In case you don't only want to drop the prefix for article page ranges, but to omit them entirely, use the following code (which makes the above format redefinition superfluous):

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{%
    \clearfield{pages}%
  }{%
  }%
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that does it. I assume that the code in question is:

    \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}%
What exactly does this mean? Only for learning benefits ;-)

Comment: @Jan I added a short explantion to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The technique you used replaces the language string for "pages" throughout the entire bibliography, and also presupposes that you do not write any page references in the entries for your articles (but what if you need them for another paper, with another citation style?). @lockstep's answer is more targeted, but (unless I am mistaken) also supposes that you omit the page numbers in your `.bib` file.

In order to prevent printing the page number altogether, how about this:

```
\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
    \printfield{note}%
    %\setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
    %\printfield{pages}%
    \newunit}
```

The `note+pages` macro is used by the `standard.bbx` file for displaying the page numbers of articles. It is the file called by `authoryear` for formatting the bibliography.

Comment: With @locksteps solution, you don’t have to omit the pages in the `.bib` file.

Comment: Good catch, with regard to omitting prefixes vs. omitting the entire data! I've updated my answer to include my preferred method (`\clearfield`), but +1 for your one.

Comment: @domwass Actually, re-reading the OP's question makes me think it was quite ambiguous, and iennissei's answer was helpful.

Comment: @lockstep Yes, the ambiguity of the question was behind my reasoning, but I very much like your solutions.

Comment: This solution works very well. With the `\DeclareFieldFormat` solution, I would get my bib entries ending with a comma instead of a period.