# Page prefix missing for some entries

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` with `authoryear` and for some of my entries, the page prefix (“S.” in my case) is missing, where I would actually like to have it.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,language=ngerman]{biblatex}
```

This entry

```
@ARTICLE{Umemura1990,
  author = {Umemura, Takashi},
  title = {Ippyôsei ni yatô hanpatsu},
  journaltitle = {Asahi Shinbun},
  date = {1990-11-11},
  titleaddon = {Oppositionsparteien lehnen Ein-Stimmen-System ab},
  issuetitle = {Morgenausgabe},
  issue = {Tôkyô},
  pages = {2-3}
}
```

gives me this:

[image: Bibliography entry with pages]

But this entry

```
@ARTICLE{McMaster1963,
  author = {John McMaster},
  title = {The Takashima Mine: British Capital and Japanese Industrialization},
  journaltitle = {Business History Review},
  year = {1963},
  volume = {38},
  number = {3},
  pages = {215–239}
}
```

only yields the following:

[image: Bibliography entry without pages]

Is there any reason why the “S.” is omitted in the second case? I have looked around in `authoryear.bbx`, `biblatex.def` and `standard.bbx` and could not find anything that would clue me in. To me this seems particularly strange because both entries use the `article` driver. I have even found a question where someone wants to *get rid* of the page prefix ([biblatex: no pages for article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40023/biblatex-no-pages-for-article)) so I suppose it should be there by default. `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1}}` also lead to no result.

Comment: The second entry uses the Unicode EN dash in the `pages` field. If your input encoding accepts this character, add `\DeclareRangeChars*{–}` to your preamble. Otherwise try using the Ascii character `-` as the range separator throughout your `bib` file.

Comment: Thanks, both of your suggestions worked, you might want to turn your comment into an answer. Seems like I have developed a habit of automatically typing in the correct range dash—this is what UTF-8 input encoding does to you ;)

Comment: If you are using `biber`, the 1.7 DEV version on SF now recognises everything with the Unicode 6.1 "Dash Punctuation" property as a range sep. `biber` always parses range fields and converts the range separator to `\bibrangedash` in the .bbl

Comment: Glad to hear about that. As of now, I am on 1.5 and because TL 2012 has already been frozen, I think I am going to wait till the release of TL 2013, so I can update `biber` through `tlmgr` and just use @Audrey’s suggestion. But thanks for the info, nevertheless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second entry uses the Unicode EN dash in the pages field. Without biber 1.7+ and a compatible biblatex version, this character is not recognized as a page range indicator by default. If your input encoding accepts this character, add `\DeclareRangeChars*{–}` to your preamble. Otherwise try using one of the default range indicator Ascii characters (e.g. `-`) or commands (e.g. `\bibrangedash`, `\textendash`, `\textemdash`) throughout your `bib` file. A quick way to do this is to re-encode your `bib` file to Ascii with:

```
biber --tool --output_encoding=ascii --output_safechars <file name>.bib
```

from the command line.